# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set magento2 aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento

I have installed magento on aws instance.

When i tried to go to root sudo su
it is giving me error

> sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

I have tried move volume  from running instance into temp vol(create new instance) and change some permission and   put back  volume  on main instance  but its not working.
My website not working and showing  some funny output  -please see attached pic

[funny output from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL95v.png)

Will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all we will get an error which will show:

> “sudo /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit
>   set aws.

This means the sudo root permission has been over written, which creates restriction of using sudo and it leads you into problems like all the root access you lost and getting back from this situation is not a one way solution, so lets take a look and try to back track:

1. Do not forget to create a back up using AMI or snapshot
2. Create a totally new instance and detach the effected volume from the last instance attach it back to the newly created instance.
3. Login to new instance and create a new folder in the root, and start operation as root.
4. Now time to check the attached drive in new instance: “mount”… “fdisk -l | grep Disk”.
5. Create new folder in root directory: “mkdir /newfolder”
6. Now mount the vol: “sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /newfolder/”
7. After mount if we check the permission we will see that the newfolder permission got changed after mounting because of the effected volume:
8. Now we can change the permission of the mounted drive by default into root under root groups: “chown -R root: root newcopy/”, after the operation if we check the permision it will be root. After this permission we have to follow the same steps to change other’s permission inside the folder, newcopy/usr/bin/: “chmod 4755 sudo”.
9. After all the operation we have to detach the vol and attach that to the last volume